# Relative paths in odoo config file (oddo.conf)

Tags: odoo

I know this can be practically solved by using absolute paths, but I'm interested on knowing how relatives paths are resolved in this file.

Are the relative paths in the 'odoo.conf' resolved from 'odoo.conf' file itself, or the odoo-bin file (the python executable)?

I.E. I have cloned Odoo from github to odoo16 folder:

```
/home/myuser/OdooDevPyCharmProject/
    ├── odoo16/
    │   ├── odoo-bin
    │   ├── addons/
    │   └── odoo/
    │       └── addons/
    └── confs/
        └── odoo.conf
```

I have a 'confs' folder for 'odoo.conf'. In this file should I set:

```
#relative to odoo-bin
addons_path = odoo/addons
```

or

```
#relative to odoo.conf
addons_path = ../odoo16/odoo/addons
```

Thanks!

NOTE: I have read that the 'addons' folder in the same folder than 'odoo-bin' does not need to be declared in 'addons_path', as it contains the default modules, and allways must be there.